# Ordered listing images in a div

Tags: jquery, css

I am try to list some images in a div but the images listed only in a single row but I want to list it in many rows (I want to see next row image after 3 images) my code is listed here

```
<?php
  foreach ($list as $row)
  {?>
    <div>
      <a href="<?php echo base_url("./resources/images/"); echo $row['image'];?>">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url("./resources/images/"); echo $row['image'];?>" alt="" />
      </a>
    </div>
  <?php 
  }
?>
```

please help[image] this is my listing and I want this listing like this
[image]

Comment: Please use `isotope`  -   
https://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attain this by using `float: left` property and after every third child, you can just apply `clear: left;`. This will allow only three `div`'s in one row as per your demand. Also, if I may add, do check about `flex-basis` property which can also solve your problem.

Here is a working solution:

```css
.child {
    background: grey ;
    height: 150px;
    float: left;
    margin:15px 0 0 15px;
    width:150px;
    
}
.child:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: left;   
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```